# Gibbs sampling example of a bivariate normal with unknown correlation

Tags: bayesian, correlation, gibbs, conditional-distribution

I'm looking for an example of using Gibbs sampling with a bivariate normal, where the correlation parameter is not fixed or known. In other words, what is the conditional distribution of the correlation $\rho$?

There are many examples out there showing Gibbs sampling with the bivariate normal, but they all assume that $\rho$ is known.

Comment: Thanks, Xi'an! I just got out of hospital, a harrowing experience in these corona times.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing the LaTeX from Wikipedia, the joint density of a bivariate $(X,Y)$ is given by
$$f(x,y) =
      \frac{1}{2 \pi  \sigma_X \sigma_Y \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\\
     \times \exp\left(
        -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[
          \frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2} +
          \frac{(y-\mu_Y)^2}{\sigma_Y^2} -
          \frac{2\rho(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}
        \right]
      \right)$$
Therefore, assuming a flat prior on $\rho\in(-1,1)$, the full conditional posterior of $\rho$ has density proportional to
$$\pi(\rho)\propto\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\times \exp\left(
        -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[
          \frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2} +
          \frac{(y-\mu_Y)^2}{\sigma_Y^2}\right]\right)\\\times\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[-\frac{2\rho(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}\right]\right)$$
that is
$$\pi(\rho)\propto\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\times \exp\left(
        -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[
          \frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2} +
          \frac{(y-\mu_Y)^2}{\sigma_Y^2}\right]\right)\\
\times \exp\left(\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\frac{2\rho(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}\right)$$
which is thus a density of the form
$$g(\rho)\propto (1-\rho^2)^{-1/2}\exp\{-\beta/(1-\rho^2)+\alpha\rho/(1-\rho^2)\}\mathbb{I}_{(-1,1)}(\rho)$$
with $|\alpha|\le\beta$. Since this does not appear to be a standard distribution, one solution is to run Metropolis within Gibbs.

> **I however answered a [very similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/305933/7224) a while ago, using
>   accept reject to simulate exactly this full conditional.**

Comment: Thank you! We'll pursue this and post example code for others' benefit.